# How to use "to be" at the end of a sentence

Tags: question-marks

I have some confusion about this; for example:

> Where is the bank?
>
> I don't know where the bank **is**.

I don't know how *to be* is used at the end of sentences.

Comment: As an aside, those two sentences are fine as they are right now.

Comment: And here I thought you wanted to know about the sentence, "I don't know where the bank is now, but I know where it used to be."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a basic sentence:

> The bank is **there**.

We can turn this into a *wh*-question by replacing *there* with *where*:

> The bank is **where**?  *(inappropriate in most circumstances)*

This kind of question is acceptable in a few limited circumstances, but **most** *wh*-questions have two additional things done to them:

1. *wh*-fronting.  We move *where* to the front of the sentence:

   > **Where** the bank is ____?  *(inappropriate in most circumstances)*

   It leaves behind a **gap**, which I've marked with a blank (____).  (The gap is usually not written.)  The word *where* and the gap refer to the same thing.  What's important is this: **you can't add a complement after *is* because there's a gap there.**

   "Where the bank is?" is only appropriate in a few limited circumstances, like if you're repeating something back to someone.  It's usually incorrect.  To fix it, we need to do one more thing:
2. Subject-auxiliary inversion.  The subject (*the bank*) and the auxiliary verb (*is*) switch places:

   > **Where** is the bank ____?

   Subject-auxiliary inversion marks a sentence as a **direct question**.  With both *wh*-fronting and subject-auxiliary inversion, we've created a complete question ("Where is the bank?").

However, if you want to use "where the bank is" as an **indirect question**, you don't switch the subject and auxiliary:

> [ **where** the bank is ____ ]

This is a relative clause.  It doesn't work as a direct question, which means it doesn't work as a sentence on its own.  That's why I didn't capitalize *where* or put a period at the end.  But it does work as an indirect question, as part of a larger declarative sentence:

> I don't know [ **where** the bank is ____ ].

In this example, we've fronted *where*, but we did **not** invert the subject and auxiliary.  That would be ungrammatical because it's not a direct question:

> *I don't know [ **where** is the bank ____ ].  *(ungrammatical)*

(Technically, there are circumstances where it's possible to embed a direct question, particularly in speech.  But I'm ignoring that here.)

Answer (score 1):

You use it the same way you do any other verb at the end of the sentence, or in any other location.  The verb *to be* follows the same placement rules as any verb in English.

The normal order is [subject-verb-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object).  When there is no object, the verb comes last in the sentence, as in your example.

> I don't know where the *bank* **is**.
>
> I don't know what *Bob* **did**.
>
> *I* **sang**.
>
> *Fish* **swim**.

The verb *to be* could be substituted for any of these other verbs, and still be grammatically correct, but substantially boring:

> I don't know what *Bob* **was**.
>
> *I* **am**.
>
> *Fish* **are**.

Perhaps the reason you find *to be* at the end of a sentence to be odd, is that the verb *to be* is often a [helping verb](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-what_classification-helping.htm), and when it is, it is not found at the end of a sentence:

> *Bob* **was singing**.
>
> *I* **am cooking**.
>
> *Fish* **are swimming**.

Or we use the *to be* verb as descriptive:

> *Bob* **was** ill.
>
> *I* **am** tall.
>
> *Fish* **are** tasty!

So in summary: Use the verb *to be* at the end of a sentence any time it conveys the meaning you desire, and in exactly the same way you do with any other verb.